# I have a problem about the when I connect the laragon in phpmyadmin I can't connect

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, laragon

I ussualy use xammp but I wanted to make a change and I use start the laragon but I have a problem: I can't connect the phpmyadmin when I use laragon. When I use xammp there is a not problem phpmyadmin is working. In short, when I log in with XAAMP, there is no problem, but when I try to log in with Laragon, it gives an error. The error message is as attached. I am using Laravel, so I chose to switch to Laragon. I am making the database settings in env in the Laragon files. Is there any other solution you can suggest?

[image]

I tried and researched everything that could be tried, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please post the English version of your error. Please don't post [images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: did you set the password ?

Comment: you tried using with or without password?

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing xampp phpmyadmin while the laragon started you will not be able to used it because laragon has it's own mysql database. You can access it by clicking database beside terminal button.

[image]

If you want to install phpmyadmin in your laragon, you may visit this page: https://dev.to/dendihandian/adding-phpmyadmin-to-laragon-lite-j96
Hope it helps!